# Is there a better way to get content of Json file?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a json data in this form:

```
[
  {
    "var1": "string",
    "var2": "string",
    "id": "dd4c6519",
  }
]
...
[
  {
    "var1": "string",
    "var2": "string",
    "id": "il4c7802",
  }
]
```

The only unique parameter in each entry is the id. I would like to get the var1 and var2 where id = il4c7802 
This is what I have tried.

```
//Get file content
$url_ga = "http://filescatins/";
$json_ga = file_get_contents($url_ga);
$obj_ga = json_decode($json_ga);
foreach($obj_ga as $row) 
{
?>
<script>
var ga_id = "<?php echo $row->id; ?>";
var ga_var1 = "<?php echo $row->var1; ?>";
var ga_var2 = "<?php echo $row->var2; ?>";
var ar_var = [ga_var1, ga_var2];

// fill dict
val_dict(ga_id, ar_var);
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here is the dictionary function

```
<script>
var dict_data = new Object();
function val_dict(key, val){
    dict_data[key] = val;
    return dict_data;
}
</script>
```

I could now list the keys using `Object.keys(dict_data)`, then find the position of my key  `id = il4c7802` in the list, and get the values corresponding to it. 
My question is to know whether there is a better way to achieve this. Could I get those values (var1 and var2) without saving each entry of them in a dictionary ? 
Could I achieved the same result just by having an array of id? Something like, 
`get var1 and var2 where id = il4c7802`

Answer (score 0):

This function gets the value based on the id you have passed to it

```
function get_val(id){
    return dict_data[id];
    // This is another way of accessing JS objects
    // If you use dict_data.id, it will look for a key with the name "id" instead of the value in the variable "id"
}
```

If it doesn't get the value with that id, it returns `"undefined"` ... this could be useful to give a callback on whether the id exists or not for example:

```
var some_id = "1234567ABC";
if(get_val(some_id) == undefined){
    console.log("Invalid id!");
}
else {
    console.log("Values are: " + get_val(some_id));
}
```

Also since `ar_var` is an array, the value being returned is also an array with the 2 values for `var1` and `var2`